# compile fail on iterating list

Tags: java, list, collections

i have a list Like this-`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, [1, 2, 3]]]`

below is my code-

```
    List<Object> inner1=new ArrayList<Object>();
    inner1.add(1);
    inner1.add(2);
    inner1.add(3);

    List<Object> inner2=new ArrayList<Object>();
    inner2.add(4);
    inner2.add(5);
    inner2.add(6);
    inner2.add(inner1);

    List<Object> outer=new ArrayList<Object>();
    outer.add(inner1);
    outer.add(inner2);

    System.out.println(outer);


    for(List<Object> list:(List<List<Object>>)outer){   //compile fail
        for(Object innerData:(List<Object>)list){
             if (innerData instanceof List) {
                for(Integer data: (List<Integer>)innerData){
                    System.out.println(data);
                }

            }else{
                System.out.println(innerData);
            }

        }
    }
```

why this compile fail on iterating outer list.

I know all the Object in outer is of `List<Object>` so this is a `List<List<Object>>`

on casting outer in `List<List<Object>>` result is compile fail.

More over if this is not desired result this should be `ClassCastException` rather than compile fail?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: [4, 5, 6, [1, 2, 3]]] this seems wrong... here you have a List that has different types of elements: 1 number - a list of numbers.

Comment: @Stultuske this list is a list of Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first for-loop to:

```
for (List<Object> list : (List<List<Object>>) (List) outer) {
```

Although a `List<Object>` could certainly contain elements of type `List<Object>`, you cannot, within the constraints of the type system, say that a `List<Object>` can be cast to `List<List<Object>>`.

Because, you could have actually put something else in the list as well, like a `String` or an `Integer`. And if you then tried to iterate over it as if it was a `List<List<Object>>`, you'd get some very weird results (because you can't cast `Integer` or `String` to `List<Object>`)

If you're 100% certain that your list outer doesn't contain anything that's not a `List<Object>`, then you can tell Java to treat it like that in the way that I described above.

But you should realize that Java is not LISP or some other heavily list-based functional language.

What you're doing is a very improper way of data-modelling in Java. If you don't need static typing (and with all your casts and treating things as `Object`, that's what you're doing), then you shouldn't be using Java as a language; pick another language that fits your problem domain better!

Comment: fantastic, this is working.but why  `(List<List<Object>>)(List<Object>)outer` is again compile fail.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians I expanded my answer. It's basically because you're doing something that breaks the type system for generics. You can do so, if you want, by telling Java that your list does not have a generic type (the cast to `(List)`), but that's a hack that can bite you later.

Comment: Yup it can `(because you can't cast Integer or String to List<Object>)` but how does compiler knowing this at all,this should cause trouble at runtime when this will be object of any other type rather than List.

Comment: The compiler has specific rules/restrictions for generics. Partly because they wanted a more correct typesystem for generics than for arrays, partly because generics only exist at compile time - at runtime, the JVM doesn't know whether a List is a `List<String>` or a `List<List<Object>>`. See this links for more info on the restrictions for casting generics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCast

Answer (score 1):

`outer` is not a `List<List<Object>>`, so you can't cast it do that.

You should check each element of the outer List to see if it's a List itself.

```
for(Object obj : outer) {
    if (obj instanceof List) {
        List list = (List)obj;
        for(Object innerData: list) {
            if (innerData instanceof List) {
                for (Object obj2 : (List)innerData) {
                    if (obj2 instanceof Integer) {
                        Integer data = (Integer) obj2;
                        ...
```

EDIT:

If the outer List can contain only List elements, you can simplify the code by changing the type of `outer` to `List<List<Object>>`.

```
List<List<Object>> outer=new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
```

Then you'll have

```
for(List<Object> list : outer) {
    for(Object innerData: list) {
        if (innerData instanceof List) {
            for (Object obj2 : (List)innerData) {
                if (obj2 instanceof Integer) {
                    Integer data = (Integer) obj2;
                    ...
```

Comment: outer is a list of `Object` and these `Object`s are again a `List<Object>`,so can be not do like this.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians I don't understant your comment. Yes, outer is a `List<Object>`, which means iterating over it gives elements of type Object, and you have to check their type before casting them to something else.

Comment: Object`s are again a `List<Object>` means all object added inside is of type List only

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians In that case, change the type of `outer` as I suggested in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Compile error because your outer type is `List<Object>` cannot be cast to `List<List<Object>>`.

Your code should be:

```
for (Object list : outer) {  
    if (list instanceof List) {
        for (Object innerData : (List<Object>) list) {
            if (innerData instanceof List) {
                for (Integer data : (List<Integer>) innerData) {
                    System.out.println(data);
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println(innerData);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `outer`of type `List<List<Object>>` and you won't need to cast at all.

Answer (score 0):

Outer is not defined as List>.

Use it like this -

```
for(Object list : outer){
    List<Object> o = (List<Object> list);
    // Remaining logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

changes in for loop,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> inner1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        inner1.add(1);
        inner1.add(2);
        inner1.add(3);

        List<Object> inner2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        inner2.add(4);
        inner2.add(5);
        inner2.add(6);
        inner2.add(inner1);

        List<Object> outer = new ArrayList<Object>();
        outer.add(inner1);
        outer.add(inner2);

        System.out.println(outer);

        for (Object list : outer) {
            if (list instanceof List) {
                for (Object innerData : (List<Object>) list) {
                    if (innerData instanceof List) {
                        for (Integer data : (List<Integer>) innerData) {
                            System.out.println(data);
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println(innerData);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, [1, 2, 3]]]
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a method like:

```
static void printFlat(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof List<?>)
        for (Object element : (List<?>)object)
            printFlat(element);
    else
        System.out.println(object);
}
```

and

```
    printFlat(outer);
```

Comment: what does `?` means here....Is this menas `object` is of type `List` or Lists super class?

Comment: `List<?>` means List of unknown.  See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).